# Непонятное поведение Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Есть вот такая вот модель:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Collection1 { get; set; } = new List<User>();

    public virtual ICollection<User> Collection2 { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

Дальше немного наполняем нашу базу:

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var user1 = new User();
var user2 = new User();
var user3 = new User();
user1.Name = "user1";
user2.Name = "user2";
user3.Name = "user3";
user1.Collection1.Add(user2);
user2.Collection1.Add(user3);
context.Users.Add(user1);
context.Users.Add(user2);
context.Users.Add(user3);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Как видно ни одному пользователю в `Collection2` никого не добавляем.

Дальше делаю вот такой запрос:

```
var user2 = context.Users.First(user => user.Name == "user2");
foreach (var u in user2.Collection2)
    Console.WriteLine($"{user2.Name}  Collection2 {u.Name}");
```

И получаю:

> user2  Collection2 user1

Откуда у `user2` во второй коллекции появляется `user1` если я в нее никого не добавлял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `Collection1` и `Collection2` автоматически определились как взаимно обратные.

Поэтому, при появлении в контексте связи *user1 - (Collection1) - user2* обратная связь добавилась автоматически.

Если коллекции являются независимыми, а не взаимно обратными - настройте связь между навигационными свойствами через переопределение [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg679267(v=vs.113).aspx) или через расстановку правильных [`InversePropertyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Но как в данной ситуации использовать `InversePropertyAttribute`? У меня ж в сущности хранятся две колекции этой же сущности. Вы не могли бы написать небольшой пример?

Comment: @Lightness так же, как обычно. Указать обратное навигационное свойство, если оно есть.

Comment: А если нет обратного навигационного свойства как в моей ситуации, то как поступить?

Comment: @Lightness создать его или воспользоваться альтернативным методом -- К.О.

Comment: Создать его не получится. Если переопределять `OnModelCreating` то что там написать нужно? Напишите, пожалуйста, небольшой пример, т.к. я не особо знаком с `EntityFramework` и не понимаю что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @Lightness как говорится, *"когда ничего не работает - самое время почитать документацию"*. На этом сайте вопросы полагается задавать *после* ее прочтения, а не вместо.